# Form sometimes fails to send $_POST data to PHP script

Tags: php, html

It is happening randomly. I've noticed it usually fails after 2nd or 3rd attempt. Using $_REQUEST doesn't seem to work either. Here is my form-

```
<form method="post" action='updateImage' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="uname" value="user">
<input type="hidden" name="image" value="photograph">
<label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click here to select an image">
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" class="input" onchange="preview()" style="display: none;" required/>
</label>
<input type="submit" name="submit_student_photograph" value="Update Student Photograph">
</form>
```

Edit 1: Here is the php script-

```
$foldername = $this->student()->setStudentData($_POST)->setFoldername();
  $filename = $foldername.'_photograph_1';
  $handle = new upload($_FILES['file']);
  if ($handle->uploaded) {
    $handle->file_new_name_body   = $filename;
    $handle->image_resize         = true;
    $handle->image_x              = 600;
    $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
    $handle->process('all_student_files/'.$foldername);
    if ($handle->processed) {
      $handle->clean();
      $_SESSION['success'] = "Image has been updated.";
      header("Location:?controller=students&action=showStudentProfile&uname=".$_POST['uname']."#".$_POST['direction']);
    } else {
      $_SESSION['error'] = "There was a problem updating the Image. Please try again!";
      header("Location:?controller=students&action=showStudentProfile&uname=".$_POST['uname']."#".$_POST['direction']);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Show the relevant PHP too

Comment: If you're dealing with files you should use `$_FILES` not `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST`

Comment: Could you show console request, when it fails ?

Comment: I've added the relevent php script. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've found the cause for this problem! PHP settings doesn't accept any file that exceeds the size of 2 MB, hence the execution of my script fails.